# Prove that if $u+U=w+W$ then $U=W$ (where $u$,$w$ are vecotrs and $U$,$W$ are subspaces)

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

having a hard time with this one:

$V$ is a subspace over $F$,

$u$ and $w$ are vectors in $V$,

$U$ and $W$ are subspaces of $V$

prove that if $u+U = w+W$ then $U=W$

($u+U$ is defined as $\{u+v~:~v \in U\}$)

Thanks in advance for your help.
I know that in order to show that  $U=W$ I need to show that they are included in each other from each direction but I just don't know how to show that...

Comment: What did you try so far? Your idea is good - how did you start?

Comment: Hint: Given $u+U$ you can recover $U$ as the set of differences
$$U=\{x-y\mid x,y\in u+U\}.$$ Do you then see a way of using the assumption $u+U=w+W$?

Comment: Hint: 0 is in both  subspaces, so $u \in w+W$ and $w \in u+U$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivilent to $U = (w-u) + W$, then $U = W$.

Denote $w-u$ by $\alpha$, so if $U \ne W$, WLOG, asuume $U \not \subset W$then there exists $x \in U$, $x \not \in W$. So $2x \in U,2x \not \in W$

Then, due to $U = \alpha + W$, we have there exists $w_1,w_2 \in W$, such that
$x = \alpha + w_1, 2x = \alpha + w_2$, so $x = w_2 - w_1 \in W$.

A contradiction!

Comment: Thank you, I belive I got it now. BIG help!